# App Id OneSignal return null in flutter ios App

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, flutter, onesignal

App Id OneSignal in flutter ios app return null when i build in xcode.  even though i have fill it on .env file.
it gives output like this

[image]

[image]

anyone have experience trouble like this. please help

thanks before

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because the IOS simulator does not support subscribing and sending notifications. For testing you should use a real device.

Comment: i've try used a real device but the result was same. is the any other possibilities?

Comment: well as i can see from the logs you need to follow the OneSignal documentation and have a valid ios push certificate, also implement the code as it is on the example shown in the flutter package.